# By design, why was the value parameter of Html.RadioButton made as a type of object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By design, why was  the `value` parameter of `Html.RadioButton` made as a type of `object` rather than `string`?

```
string RadioButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a radio button could have any value and when the helper decides whether it should be checked or not it looks for a corresponding value in the model state.

For example:

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("foo", 123) %>
```

and inside the controller you could pass integer value:

```
ViewData["foo"] = 123;
```

and the helper will automatically select the radio button. If you have a complex object it would use the [`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx) method.

Comment: Boxing is expensive I think. Why don't we make the `value` param of type `String` and invoke ToString() for any data passed to it? I might be wrong.